# Enable/Disable driver on UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, system.management

I need to Enable/Disable a Network driver on a UWP application.

System.Management Namespace is available only for .Net applications so I can't use this dll with UWP application.

It is forbidden to reach the driver or there is another way to do it?

Comment: UWP was made to make users feel good about downloading an app from the Store.  Secure about them running in a sandbox, having been reviewed and certified, a rock-hard guarantee that such an app cannot do anything to mess with the machine.  It doesn't even have an api to do such things.

Comment: What requirement is driving the use of UWP? Can you meet the same requirement with a Win32 app?